# Does window.addEventListener('message') overwrite other listeners?

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I've got some code that communicates with an iframe using `.postMessage()`, meaning it needs to add a listener on `message` to receive communication from the iframe. I'm using the usual code for that:

```
window.addEventListener('message', processMessage, false);
```

This code runs on a client's page that has a bunch of other stuff on it: Analytics, social buttons, etc. etc. I noticed when I added a `console.log` to the `processMessage` function to debug communication from the iframe, it was picking up a lot of other traffic from third-party plugins that also use `.postMessage`.

It's not a problem to ignore them, since I'm looking for very specific messages from the iframe, but I want to make sure I'm not overwriting whatever listener was supposed to pick up those messages from the FB script and so forth. I've had issues before with multiple `window.onresize` events overwriting one another. Is that an issue with the event listener for messages?

Comment: Specifically using `addEventListener` will not overwrite any listeners. And in regards to your "filtering", look at the MDN docs for `postMessage` - there's a way to filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: You can find a good explanation of all the ways to bind event handlers, and their differences here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`addEventListener` does not overwrite existing event listeners, it simply adds a new one as the method name implies.  Existing listeners must be removed using the `removeEventListener` method.

[addEventListener info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

[removeEventListener info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener)