# Facebook login popup not closing after successful login and I'm getting no response

Tags: angular, facebook, mastercard

I'm trying to use Facebook SDK in my angular app for implementing login functionality using facebook, The iframe opens normally and the process of login works, but after a successful login the iframe is not closing and I'm not getting any response (token) in my code. I'm also including this script in my index.html file and using it for online payment:

```
    <script src="https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/51/checkout.js" data-cancel="cancelCallback"
            data-complete="completePaymentCallback" data-timeout="timeoutCallback">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function cancelCallback() {
        document.dispatchEvent(new Event('payment-cancel', {bubbles: true}));
      }

      function completePaymentCallback(data) { //console.log(data);
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('payment-completed', {bubbles: true, detail: data}));
      }

      function timeoutCallback() {
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('payment-timeout', {bubbles: true}))
      }
    </script>
```

In the payment script I'm registering callbacks to handle the payment status, this script is responsible for opening a popup to handle online payment. I figured out that if I don't include this script in my index.html. facebook login works perfectly fine.

There is a link for an image explaining the state of the iframe `https://i.ibb.co/TRY2PJS/facebook-login.jpg`

The tutorial I followed for using Facebook API can be found here:
`https://medium.com/@sarat.e99/facebook-login-oauth2-from-angular-6-f55a96c2be00`

The mastercard javascript file is emitting errors in my console, here is the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at checkout.js:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
    at globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1781)
```

The code snippet in the mastercard script that is throwing errors in my console:

```
var xDomain = function(targetWindow, targetHost, name) {
                var json3 = "undefined" != typeof JSON3 ? JSON3 : require("./json3.js"),
                    callbacks = {};
                ! function(callback) {
                    window.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener("message", callback) : window.attachEvent("onmessage", callback)
                }(function(event) {
                    var payload = "string" == typeof event.data ? JSON.parse(event.data) : event.data,
                        type = payload.type,
                        data = payload.data;
                    if (type && callbacks.hasOwnProperty(type)) return callbacks[type](data)
                });
```

Comment: any errors in console??do u have everything setteld up from fb developer?

Comment: Yes, I have errors being emitted from the mastercard script, It is somehow listening to every event happing in the application and trying to parse it. here is a link for an image containing the error `https://i.ibb.co/fQbxLGC/master-card-error.jpg` and here is the link for the tutorial I followed to set up the SDK `https://medium.com/@sarat.e99/facebook-login-oauth2-from-angular-6-f55a96c2be00`

Comment: can u show the ts file code as well

Comment: yes sure, here is a link for it: `https://www.pastiebin.com/5cd95ad7c212a`

Comment: also, this is a screenshot from the code snippet in the mastercard code that is throwing the exception: `https://i.ibb.co/7KH6MN5/checkout-js-event-listener.png`

Comment: Please go read [ask], and show code snippets relevant to the problem and error messages directly in the question in text form, properly formatted, instead of just dumping them on external sites.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I updated the question description

Comment: Looks like this mastercard script thinks it is responsible for handling _all_ message events caused by other tabs sending data to the tab using postMessage. Ideally this should be fixed by the script provider - they should properly check the origin of the message, and then only handle the messages that are coming from their domain. Otherwise you would probably have to unbind the event handlers this script is setting, and replace them with your own that do basically the same, but implement this extra check.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding that quickly, so could you please point me to the way I can unbind the event handlers or point me to some document. because I don't think the script provider will fix that Issue. really appreciate your help

Comment: The counterpart to `addEventListener` would be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener, and to `attachEvent` it is `detachEvent`. But I can’t guarantee this will work, it might depend on where and when `xDomain` gets called by the original script, and whether you have access to `callback` from outside the script in the first place (because you need the reference to the originally bound handler function to be able to un-bind it again.) The new handler function would then have to check `event.origin` first, and only proceed if it is the expected one.

Comment: Thank you so much, will try this out. really hope it works

Comment: unfortunately unbinding the event listener didn't work as you pointed out I didn't have access to `callback` from outside the script. but reading another StackOverflow question regarding `addEventListener` overwriting other listeners I came across this one `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204902/does-window-addeventlistenermessage-overwrite-other-listeners` which states that adding listeners don't overwrite original ones. so in principle the message should be propagated to all listeners, so why FB SDK fails to catch it?

Comment: Also, I should mention that I managed to get login with Google working fine and from my point of view it is doing the same thing, iframe pops up and sending data to the tab using postMessage.